# PHP: Using nested 'foreach' loops to output XML data from SOAP response not working

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing, foreach

Ok, so I'm requesting state and city from a service using SOAP and using a 'foreach' loop to output the states, and within each of those iterations, I'm using another 'foreach' loop to output the cities within each state.

First, the SOAP call:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://devxml.#####.com/golfService.asmx?wsdl", array(‘features’ => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));

$regionList = $client->Areas(
    array(
        'Hdr' => array(
            'ResellerId' => '#####', 
            'SourceCd' => 'A', 
            'UserIp' => '207.58.123.121', 
            'gsDebug' => '1'
          ),
        'Req' => array(
            'CountryID' => 'USA',
            'RegionID' => ''
        )
    )
)
```

...which returns the following the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<AreasResponse xmlns="http://xml.####.com/">
<AreasResult>
<RetCd>0</RetCd>
<RetMsg />
<Countries>
    <Country>
        <id>USA</id>
        <nm>United States</nm>
        <Regions>
            <Region>
                <id>AZ</id>
                <nm>Arizona</nm>
                <Areas>
                    <Area>
                        <id>Phoenix Northeast</id>
                        <nm>Phoenix Northeast</nm>
                    </Area>
                </Areas>
            </Region>
            <Region>
                <id>FL</id>
                <nm>Florida</nm>
                <Areas>
                    <Area>
                        <id>Ft. Myers/Naples</id>
                        <nm>Ft. Myers/Naples</nm>
                    </Area>
                    <Area>
                        <id>Miami / Ft. Lauderdale</id>
                        <nm>Miami / Ft. Lauderdale</nm>
                    </Area>
                </Areas>
            </Region>
        </Regions>
    </Country>
</Countries>
</AreasResult>
</AreasResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now, here's how I'm handling this in my PHP:

```
foreach ($regionList->AreasResult->Countries->Country->Regions->Region as $region):
    echo $region->nm . ": ";
    foreach ($region->Areas->Area as $area):
        echo $area->nm . ", ";
    endforeach;
    echo "<br />";
endforeach;
```

Ideally, this would output as:

> Arizona: Phoenix Northeast,
>   Florida: Ft. Myers/Naples, Miami / Ft. Lauderdale,

But no! It's showing up like this:

> Arizona: , ,
>   Florida: Ft. Myers/Naples, Miami / Ft. Lauderdale,

The two commas after 'Arizona:' imply there are two records, but there's only one. Even more infuriating is that it won't output the dang Area value. **What am I doing wrong?** Help me, StackOverflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: Sorry about that! I accidentally posted the question before I was finished writing it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foreach ($region->Areas->Area)` ?

Comment: Yes. That got lost in posting it here but I've corrected it.

Comment: foreach ($region->Areas as $area) { echo $area->nm }... the areas element is an array, not the area

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to arrays not being properly cast even though you're using the single array element feature. I used this function in the past that may work in this case:

```
function forceList($obj, $prop)
{
    $r = &$obj->$prop;
    return isset($r) ? is_array($r) ? $r : array($r) : array();
}

foreach (forceList($region->Areas, 'Area') as $area) { ... }
```

I know, it makes use of two ternary operators, but I did test it ;-)

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your answer. I don't really understand what your code is doing (Why pass '$obj->$prop' by reference?) but I have "solved" it my own way by writing a terribly inelegant kludge that duplicates a bunch of code and uses if statements to see if it's an object or an array.

Comment: @user it converts an object to an array and leave existing arrays alone. The reference is used to shorten the code really.